# NAT@force error when the citation is called in different ways

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

When compiling a `.tex` file that has the preamble shown at the end of this post, I get the following error:

```
 ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

 (natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.


 See the natbib package documentation for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...                                              

 l.96 ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

 ?
```

In the `.tex` file, I have declared the bibliography to be read into `library.bib`:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{./library}
```

I have analized in a very detailed way the `library.bib` file, removing each citation, one by one, until the above error disappear.

The problem was with this citation:

```
 @Article{Thermal-expansion-coefficients-Calcite-old-paper,
 author = "R. Srinivasan",
 title = "The thermal expansion of calcite form room temperature up to 400",
 journal = "Proceedings of the Indian Academy of Sciences - Section A",
 volume = "42",
 pages = "81 - 85",
 year = "1955",
 }
```

**If you try to:**

**a)** use my preamble,

**b)** copy this citation into a new `.bib` file: `library_clean.bib`,

**c)** and make the document to call to this file:

```
 This is a citation \cite{Thermal-expansion-coefficients-Calcite-old-paper}
```

and:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\bibliography{./library_clean}
```

you will get the above error.

So, this indicates that the error is related to this citation.
I have modified the citation, and the error disappears when **at least** one `-` is changed by a `_`, for example all these possibilities 1-5 do not produce the above error:

1)    `@Article{Thermal_expansion-coefficients-Calcite-old-paper,
     ...`

2)    `@Article{Thermal-expansion_coefficients-Calcite-old-paper,
     ...`

3)     `@Article{Thermal-expansion-coefficients_Calcite-old-paper,
     ...`

4)     `@Article{Thermal-expansion-coefficients-Calcite_old-paper,
     ...`

5)     `@Article{Thermal-expansion-coefficients-Calcite-old_paper,
     ...`

However, as I said, the `@Article{Thermal-expansion-coefficients-Calcite-old-paper,` **produces** that error.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Preamble:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib} 
 \usepackage{amsmath} % Required for some math elements 
 \setcitestyle{square}
 \usepackage{caption,setspace}
 \usepackage{enumerate}

 \usepackage[british]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amssymb}

 \usepackage{datetime}                           % custom date
    \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}

 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{courier}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{comment}

 \setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs

 \captionsetup{font={footnotesize,sf,small,stretch=1},labelfont=bf}

 \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}.} % Make numbering in the enumerate environment by letter rather than number (e.g. section 6)
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{color,soul}

 \newcommand\hb{HB}
 \newcommand\gb{GB}
 \newcommand\dd{DD}

 \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
```

Comment: add `numbers` to the options of package `natbib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the option `longnamesfirst` and add the option `numbers` when loading the `natbib` package. The option `longnamesfirst` only makes sense if you use authoryear-style citation call-outs. However, the `ieeetr` bibliography style can only generate numeric-style citation callouts.

Comment: Thank you very much, why in this case we require of `numbers`? What does this option do to `natbib`?

Comment: @DavidC. - Setting the option `numbers` is mostly to play it safe; it may not be needed, but it won't hurt. For sure, `longnamesfirst` must be removed.